# Nested view/controller does not receive events

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

I have a view/controller (along with a .XIB) that has a simple NavigationBar on it. The NavigationBar has a NavigationItem which has a BarButtonItem. I used IB to hook up the menuTapped event to the File Owner, and I'm able to receive the event. So far, so good.

In another project, I'm experimenting with nested controllers, using iOS 5.0 controller containment. When I nest the above view/controller (call it "MainTableViewController") to the MainViewController, I no longer receive the menuTapped event. I verified that if I took MainTableViewController and made it the main view, the event fires. But when I nest it under MainViewController, the event does not get handled by the MainTableViewController.

Here is the code I have to create the sub view/controller (I'm doing this in MainViewController viewDidLoad):

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    self.mainTableViewController = [[MainTableViewController alloc] init];
    //[self.mainTableViewController.view setUserInteractionEnabled:YES];
    [self addChildViewController:self.mainTableViewController];
    [self.mainTableViewController didMoveToParentViewController:self];

    [super viewDidLoad];

    CGRect frame = self.view.frame;
    self.mainTableViewController.view.frame = frame;
    [self.view addSubview:self.mainTableViewController.view];
}
```

That's the code I use to initialize the sub view/controller.

When I run the app, the XIB gets loaded and the UI looks fine (I can experiment with setting the frame to other coordinates, and it looks fine), but when I tap the BarButtonItem, my handler does not get called.

My understanding is that sub views should get events before parent views, so I must have hooked up the views incorrectly. I followed the controller containment sample in the iOS SDK docs, so I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: I did some more experimentation, and I used IB to connect a UIBarButtonItem* property to the BarButtonItem, and when the controller is nested, the property is NIL, but when the controller is not nested, the property is non-NIL.

Comment: So it looks like the IB things (maybe the file owner) are not hooked up properly when the controller is nested via addChildViewController.

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem - i need to use initWithNibName instead of just init. I read somewhere that init would automatically load the nib (which it does because the UI loads correctly), but it appears that the outlets aren't hooked up unless you use initWithNibName.